# Limitations of Linker with Codebase using Large Lookup Tables in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, linker, data-analysis

In my work, we have a variety of large tables storing data used for a set of multidimensional nonparametric models. Each table is a `float` array with a size of typically 200,000 to 5,000,000 elements.

Today, I was going about a normally trivial update to this codebase, updating a set of the lookup tables, when I found the compiling and linking of the project was resulting in a **Microsoft Incremental Linker has Stopped Working**, something I had not seen before. Note that the tables I was updating were growing from a size of around 290,000 elements to near 10,000,000 elements each.

I searched and found methods people recommended to tackle the problem with the Incremental Linker pop-up, but nothing fixed it. I even took the project and integrated it into VS 2012 and had it fail as well.

I knew my project compiled before, so I removed the updates and brought it back to its original state. This state compiled and linked properly as it always has. I then swapped one of the old tables with one of the new tables, and it compiled and linked properly. However, once I did another swap for an updated table, it had the same problem with linking after it compiled.

As stated before, the new tables I have been adding have about 10,000,000 elements each and are significantly larger than the old tables they are updating. Is it feasible the linker is struggling to work with these large tables? If so, why is that?

The new tables compile fine with the codebase, it is just the linker step that fails. If the size of the tables is an issue, is there any advice as to handle this problem that would still allow for keeping the nominal modeling and lookup table approach? I do recognize using a parametric model would be better from the point of view of size since it would compress the data, but my team does not want to leave their legacy approach at this time.

Note the code for each table is something along these lines:

Header File

```
// 
// dataset1.hpp
//

#ifndef dataset1_hpp_
#define dataset1_hpp_

namespace set1 {
   extern const int tableSize;
   extern const float table[];
}

#endif
```

Source File

```
//
// dataset1.cpp
//

namespace set1 {
   extern const int tableSize = 10000000;
   extern const float table[tableSize] = {
   /*... Lots of Numbers ... */
   };
}
```

Comment: The incremental link feature is not 100% solid.  If you get this error then the first thing to do is to delete the ..ilk file by hand so it starts with a fresh one.   If the error immediately repeats then you've hit an internal limit.  Most likely case I'd say, you'll have to disable it or consider starting to use a file.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes your first couple comments is what I read online and tried. However, even doing what you mentioned (and other things) sadly doesn't allow it to compile with the full dataset. What do you mean by disabling it or considering to use a file?

Comment: Can you move the data to a file rather than hard coding it?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Sadly I think not. We have to deliver a DLL to a customer that will allow them to evaluate this model thousands of times per second, so I believe having to load the data via a file would be too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

In your .cpp file you define data as extern. Why? The data is local to this .cpp file. This looks strange to me. Maybe you need:

```
//
// dataset1.cpp
//

namespace set1 {
   const int tableSize = 10000000;
   const float table[tableSize] = {
       /*... Lots of Numbers ... */
   };
}
```

I am not sure this will help, but this is something worth to try. Maybe you will simply walk around this problem.

In my past work I had problems with huge static arrays of objects (compiler had problems with handling possible exceptions from huge number of sequential ctors), but other than that huge static arrays worked fine.

Why are you using VS2010? Try the latest version (free Community 2015) at least just to check what will happen.

Comment: The `extern` is used because `table` and `tableSize` are used in other parts of the codebase and are defined as `extern` in the associated header. In the actual header in my codebase, it lists numerous table and tableSize variables. However, we define each table in separate .cpp files since they are large.

Comment: Also, my work is in Defense, and they don't tend to (sadly) update their tools as often as they can. I only recently got a compiler for my classified Linux environment at work that can run C++11, for example. I want to note the frustration of this problem has pushed me to request a VS 2015 license (that's the environment I have at home on my PC), so we'll see what happens.

Comment: I want to note that at the moment, given I am stuck with VS2010, this problem doesn't appear like it will be resolved. I am looking into a convenient way to change this problem into one that can use dynamic allocation and not depend on C++11 features (like initialization lists). Not finding any convenient way so far, sadly, but we'll see.

Comment: I was mentioning 2015 not because of its new features, but because they might fix their old bug. Knowing that the issue is fixed may inspite the direction of thinking.

Comment: I understand that's what you meant by mentioning VS2015, that's the main reason I want it too. But getting extra language features would be a pleasant bonus since that's what I use when I develop at home.