# Maximum array size allowed for an extern array in C++ on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker, extern

I asked a question yesterday which is found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900092/limitations-of-linker-with-codebase-using-large-lookup-tables-in-visual-studio-2)** trying to understand any potential problems with using large lookup tables specified via an extern array. These tables are all used for a set of nonparametric models that must be built into a DLL for our customer to use, where the DLL is expected to make computations with the at say 1000Hz or so.

Now in my project, the assortment of extern array lookup tables in total store about 66.2M floats, so in total around 265MB of data. The project, with all these tables, will compile fine but fail to complete the linking.  However, the project compiles and links fine when I have less than about 180MB of data stored in the extern arrays.

Since my post yesterday, I have gathered a lot of evidence suggesting my project is hitting a limit on the amount of data I can have stored in extern arrays. Is there any actual limit with how much data can be stored in a set of extern arrays/variables? Is there maybe a bug in the linker that could break by having too much data in extern arrays? If there is some limit, is there a way to bump the limit to something higher or work around this issue somehow?

Note that my project is a Win32 project.

**Edit**

Note that more info about the problem, like the error that appears, is in my link at the start of the post. Below is some screen shots of the pop-up and message in VS 2010:

[image: Pop-up of Incremental Linker Failing]

[image: Visual Studio Linking Output after Incremental Linker Fails]

Comment: Post the error that you are getting.

Comment: @KirillKobelev info about the error is in the link embedded in the bolded "here" in the first sentence. Note that I have already investigated the error at face value, found lots of commentary on how to fix it, tried things mentioned, and not had it be fixed. My experiments since have shown that exceeding a certain threshold of data stored in extern arrays is causing the linker to fail.

Comment: I dont get what you are doing, why extern declaring all the numbers. I expected to see `float numbers[10000]` declaring the numbers in the DLL but `extern float * numbers` in the main program.

Comment: @pm100 The nonparametric model data held in the extern arrays are used internally to the DLL, where the DLL basically just provides interfaces to compute the nonparametric model for some condition. The usage of the extern, which I am not the originator of, is to allow for swapping in new datasets of varying sizes easily. We normally have a collection of externed arrays declared in a single header, but then have each one defined in individual .cpp files.

Comment: @pm100 This extern approach just simplifies our process to go from data generation on our cluster, to automated compilation of the data into tables (the .cpp file with extern array), and then to swapping in the new tables in the project. The way it is setup just allows us to add in new data without changing any other parts of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For array this large you should use dynamic memory instead of arrays. Arrays are allocated on stack or the data segment, in your case. In fact, anything larger than around 100KB shall never be allocated as array. It can cause all kinds of trouble. And even if you did get the program running, there's likely to be some severe performance penalty.

Comment: Static arrays can be quite big. I have applications with several 10 mb static arrays each. It works like a charm.

Comment: Of course it can be. And in some cases they are preferable. But I don't think that is the norm. Besides, 10MB is hardly the same as 256MB.

Comment: @YanZhou Thanks for your comment. This is obviously a feasible route to get something working. However, I am trying to understand why the current setup isn't working, considering it has worked for years up until it passed around 180MB of data, and if there's any minor things I can change to fix it. I would ideally not have to change anything major with the code, especially if it could impact runtime performance (negatively) and the process we use to generate this DLL.

Comment: @choward Most likely a very big static array is going to impact performance negatively. I never used Windows, or MSVC, so cannot be sure about the specific.

Comment: @YanZhou Let me try the dynamic allocation route and see how things are impacted. I can work out how to convince my team of letting me remove the legacy approach if it turns out okay. Since I feel I am unaware, why do you suspect the large static array would be worse off?

Comment: A static global array will occupy the memory the whole time even if it is accessed only occasionally. This can make caching less effective

Comment: @YanZhou I have gotten the go ahead from my team to rewrite the code to use dynamic memory versus static arrays, so I will now be doing what you suggested.